# Is this statement true: $x^2<0 \ \land \ x^2 \in \mathbb{R} \ \Rightarrow \ x \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R} $?

Tags: real-numbers

So basically, is there a set containing elements not in the complex numbers that squared is a negative real number?
$ \{ x \ \vert \ x^2 \in \mathbb{R} \land x^2<0 \} \stackrel{?}{=} \emptyset $

Comment: Yes.  The square of a real number is nonnegative.

Comment: excuse me when i read the bracket notation on the LHS, it's clear that it's complex, but from the context, it seems you're dealing with something real.  in any case, this question has nothing to do with [tag:analysis], which is the logical foundations of calculus.

Comment: However, $<$ is not usually defined on $\mathbb{C}$ and it cannot be defined to make $\mathbb{C}$ an ordered field.  So, just using it pretty much says that $x^2$ is real.

Comment: I realise that I'm being stupid. I guess that is what you get for asking a question on a site where everyone is smarter than you (not being sarcastic) ...

Answer (score 1):

We can actually make a much stronger conclusion.

Let $z = re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}$. We know $z^{2} = r^{2} e^{i 2 \theta} \in \mathbb{R}$ so $2\theta = k \pi$ so $\theta = k \pi/2$. We also know $z^2 < 0$ so $r > 0$ and $\theta = \pi/2$ or $\theta = 3\pi/2$. That is, we know $z$ is of the form $\pm b i$ where $b$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x \in \mathbb R$ we have that $x^2 \ge 0.$ Hence

$$\{ x \ \vert \ x^2 \in \mathbb{R} \land x^2<0 \} = \emptyset.$$